# BitmapEncoder/ decoder, memory stream and NotSupportedException c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, memorystream

I have the following code:

```
MemoryStream imageStream;

public ImageVideoFrame(BitmapSource frame)
            {  
                imageStream = new MemoryStream();
                BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(frame));
                encoder.Save(imageStream);
                imageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            }

public BitmapSource Frame
           {
                BitmapDecoder decoder = new PngBitmapDecoder(image,
                        BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames.First();
                return bitmapSource;
           }
```

used to compress images in memory to reduce memory usage.  The problem with the above code is that I get a NotSupportedExcpetion Constructing the PngBitmapDecoder. When debugging the position of the imageStream is shown to be

Comment: your question is ending prematurely ;) and - by the way - you seem to mean `imageStream` instead of `image`. Can you post more of the exception (Message, Stacktrace?)